# NodeJS email-templates i18n localization

Tags: node.js, typescript, internationalization, i18next, email-templates

I have an issue with the localization of the pug templates combined with i18n. The language keeps rolling back to "en" language, but **I've set the locale: 'sl'** in the send() function, this is from the documentation of the email-templates.

**Here is my code in typescript:**

```
import * as path from 'path';
import Email = require("email-templates");
import { transporter } from '../mailerConnection';
import { I18n } from 'i18n';

export async function sendOutActivationEmail() {

  const i18n = new I18n();
  i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'sl'],
    directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../locales'),
    register: global
  });

  const email = new Email({
    message: {
      from: '"test" <noreplay@test.com>'
    },
    // uncomment below to send emails in development/test env:
    //send: true,
    transport: transporter,
    i18n: i18n
  });

  
  email
    .send({
      template: path.join(__dirname, '../templates', 'activation'),
      message: {
        to: 'test@gmail.com'
      },
      locals: {
        locale: 'sl',
        name: 'Test'
      }
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);

}
sendOutActivationEmail().catch(console.error);
```

**Here is html.pug template:**

```
p= __('message')
```

**Here is en.json:**

```
{
    "message": "message1"
}
```

**Here is sl.json:**

```
{
    "message": "messageSLO"
}
```

**Here is the link to email-templates localization documentation:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates#localization

What am I doing wrong that the functions doesn't switch to "sl" language? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

email-templates does not seem to document how the i18n object needs to look like, but probably you need to pass there somewhere the appropriate translations…

Alternatively, this looks more promising: https://dev.to/adrai/how-does-server-side-internationalization-i18n-look-like-5f4c#email

Answer (score 0):

Actually they use extension of the default `i18n` package is `ladjs/i18n` so the object that you pass to the email-template needs to be in different shape.

I solved my issue using the code below:

```
const email = new Email({
    message: {
        from: '"Test" <noreplay@test.com>'
    },
    // uncomment below to send emails in development/test env:
    //send: true,
    transport: transporter,
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en', 'sl'],
        directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../locales'),
        defaultLocale: 'en'
    }
});
```